# arduino auto servo movement signal from python

Tags: python, arduino, servo

how do i change the if statement in arduino in order to move the servo the same degrees as whats randomized in python?

First he's the python code:

```
import serial
import time
import random

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com4',9600)     
while True:
    low = 0; high = 180
    ran_number = random.randint(low, high)
    print ran_number
    time.sleep(1)

    arduinoData.write(ran_number)
```

python code is fine works with other things.

Now the arduino code, fix this:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;

int data;
int pin=9;
int pos = 0;

void setup() { 
  myservo.attach(9);
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite (pin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
while (Serial.available()){
  data = Serial.read();
}
if statement here.....                       
  }              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [ParseInt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt) method. Instead of using `read` in a loop and constructing your number, `Serial.ParseInt` does exactly that for you.

The correct code would be:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;

int pin = 9;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
  Serial.setTimeout(100);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int number;

  if (Serial.available()) {
    number = Serial.parseInt();
    myservo.write(number);
    delay(0.5);
  }
}
```

Notice that I set the serial timeout period to 100ms. This is to prevent `parseInt` to wait too much before deciding that it has read an entire int; otherwise when receiving a value (say, 42) it waits for about 1 second waiting for some other digits.

The Python script also has a problem or two. First, you should wait for a bit after establishing the connection because every time the serial is opened the Arduino resets, so it won't read the first couple of values. You could also get a cleaner solution by printing some string from the Arduino when ready (as the last instruction of the `setup` function, for example) and wait for it in the Python script with `readLine`.

Secondly, `arduinoData.write` takes a byte array as input, whereas you pass an int. You need to encode such int in bytes, first converting it to a string with  `str` and then encoding it with `encode`.

I got the following program working:

```
import serial
import time
import random

arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)  

# Let Arduino some time to reset
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    low = 0; high = 180
    ran_number = random.randint(low, high)
    print(ran_number)
    arduinoData.write(str(ran_number).encode())

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: sorry ignore my if statement. I understand your code provided, it makes sense, but i couldnt make it work. You mentioned to use Serial.ParseInt but you didnt use it in the code you provided! i did do simpler versions now am trying this. am kinda new to this

Comment: You are absolutely correct; I kept using Serial.read() instead of Serial.parseInt(). I edited the example accordingly now.

Comment: the servo keeps going to 90 degrees and then stops moving

Comment: It appears Python serial library also writes a newline with the string when you use `write()`; it is possible that `parseInt` is reading the correct number, then a newline that is interpreted as a 0 (therefore going back to start). I've edited the example again to move the servo once the newline is read. Also, try to sleep for 3 seconds in the python script; 1 might not be enough for the servo to move.

Comment: Tried all, now its also not moving 90 degrees. Just sitting still. Just a note that I did try the whole randomizing number and having the servo move from 0 to 180 degrees or any degree when using :     for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees

Comment: like it would work if i added 180 lines of ...  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1)  ...... each one with its own number lol, yes that's ridiculous. There must be a better way

Comment: Up until now I've given suggestion without actually trying the code; at this point I'll wait when I'm home tonight to run it with a real servo

Comment: The Python script had some problems too; I've confirmed with an Arduino Nano and an sg90 servo that my versions work

Comment: it is working, thanks for the solution. Much appreciated.